# Adding Fraction in objective c

Tags: objective-c, operators

I am new to objective-c languange, and exercising with basic math (fractions) with (+) or add operator.

here is I wanted to make 2/3 + 3/3 = 5/3, I want to display this fraction as 1 2/3.

notes : 5/3 ==> 5 is numerator, 3 is denominator.

but somehow my code wont work, I believe my mistake is on if statement on this instance.

```
- (void)printsot:(BOOL)reduceFrac;
```

but I still can't figure it out, why output doesn't print the result out, it doesn't NSLog anything.

here are my codes related to my question above

```
- (void)printsot:(BOOL)reduceFrac{
if (denominator == 0){
    NSLog(@"Result is NAN");
}
else if (denominator == 1){
    NSLog(@"%i",numerator);

}
else if (numerator == 1)  {
    NSLog(@" %i / %i",numerator,denominator);
}
else if (reduceFrac){
    Fraction *resultreduce = [[Fraction alloc]init];
    [resultreduce setTo:numerator over:denominator];
    [resultreduce reduce];
    if (resultreduce.denominator ==1) {
        NSLog(@"result is %i",resultreduce.numerator);
    }

    else if(resultreduce.numerator % resultreduce.denominator == 0){

        int result;

        result = resultreduce.numerator / resultreduce.denominator;
        NSLog(@"%i",result);

    }

    else if (resultreduce.denominator > resultreduce.numerator){

        int temp;
        int modNumerator;


        temp = resultreduce.numerator % resultreduce.denominator;

        modNumerator    = resultreduce.numerator -  temp * resultreduce.denominator;

        NSLog(@"fraction is %i %i / %i",temp,modNumerator,resultreduce.denominator);

    }


}

else{
    NSLog(@"%i/%i",numerator,denominator);
}
```

}

and here is my reduce instance method

```
- (void) reduce{
int u = numerator;
int v = denominator;
int temp = 0 ;

while (v != 0) {
    temp= u % v;
    u = v;
    v = temp;
}

numerator /=   u;
denominator /=  u;

}



- (Fraction *) add2:(Fraction *)f {

Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc]init] ;


result.numerator      = numerator * f.denominator + denominator * f.numerator;
result.denominator    = denominator * f.denominator;

return result;
```

}

---

current output from xcode

```
Prog2 Start Looping[5210:303] 2/3
Prog2 Start Looping[5210:303] +
Prog2 Start Looping[5210:303] 3/3
Prog2 Start Looping[5210:303] =
```

my main files :

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
   @autoreleasepool {

       //declare Class
       Fraction *myFraction = [[Fraction alloc]init];
       Fraction *anotherFraction = [[Fraction alloc]init];
       Fraction *resultFraction;

       //set the value of the class

       [myFraction setTo:2 over:3];    //set numerator to 2 and denominator to 3
       [anotherFraction setTo:3 over:3]; //set numerator to 3 and denominator to 3


       //display fraction's numerator and denominator

       [myFraction printsot: NO];

       NSLog(@"+");

       [anotherFraction printsot: NO];

       NSLog(@"=");



       resultFraction =   [myFraction add2:anotherFraction];

       [resultFraction printsot:YES];
   }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition

```
else if (resultreduce.denominator > resultreduce.numerator)
```

is wrong, it should be the other way around

```
else if (resultreduce.numerator >= resultreduce.denominator)
```

to cover a case like `5/3`. Also the computation of the "entire part"

```
temp = resultreduce.numerator % resultreduce.denominator;
```

should be

```
temp = resultreduce.numerator / resultreduce.denominator;
```

And don't forget to add a final `else` part to cover the case
"numerator < denominator".

Finally, if you want to work with negative fractions as well then you have to compare
the *absolute values* of numerator and denominator.